# How to pause a div using skrollr

Tags: skrollr

I've just started out using skrollr.js. I'm trying to get a div to hold / pause at a certain point. Using https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr/blob/master/examples/pausing.html and http://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr/examples/pausing.html 
as the main guides.

So from the code that I've linked, I can see that the constant set in the footer contains the length of the transition, but I've had no luck when trying to change the variable to something else, such as boxY. Even though I've changed all the box variables to boxY it doesn't work. So not sure what variables do what here. Trying to experiment to work out what it all does.

I'm trying to recreate the pausing with other code.

Sorry if this isn't very clear.

Main thing I'm trying to learn is how to keep the elements in place. A good example of this: milanart.in/philosophy

Answer (score 1):

HTML attributes are case insensitive. Quoting the docs

> Valid characters for a constant are [a-z0-9_]

https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr#working-with-constants

Edit: I just noticed that with the very latest skrollr this demo may be broken.

Comment: Main thing I'm trying to learn is how to keep the elements in place. A good example of this: http://milanart.in/philosophy/

Comment: Try with the latest skrollr 0.6.20, which I just released. And don't use upper case letters in your constants.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working in the end. At one data point have top at say 50, then later have a data point with it doing nothing, then later on change the top again.

Comment: I'm running into the same issue I would love to see a code example as I don't quite understand what you mean here.